# autoexp.dat equivalent in emacs

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, gdb, emacs23, xemacs

Does anybody know if an equivalent of "auto expansion" mechanism (works with Visual Studio ) exist for emacs (used in debug mode with gdb).
In Visual Studio i can really hover over any class instance / structure and it shows me desired structure field (which i had specify through autoexp.dat).

Right now i am using .gdbinit but every time i have to type the aliases in (gdb) prompt to get the value of an struct instance. I am wondering any plugin/extension exist which can do autoexp.dat kind of work for me.

http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2007/04/06/tweaking-autoexpdat-for-custom-types-in-vs2005

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of ways to do this in Emacs. two popular ones are [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/), which is powerful but heavyweight and can be brittle, and [auto-complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) combined with [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet#intro), e.g. [as described here](http://roupam.github.com/#sec-1-2), which was a bit slow for me but worked. All three can be installed with emacs 24's package facility.